# Couldn't match expected type `[Integer]' with actual type `Bool'

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I'm trying to iterate recursive over the list and checking if all the values are equal 0,
the error im getting is:

```
 * Couldn't match expected type `[Integer]' with actual type `Bool'
    * In the second argument of `(:)', namely `allZero s'
      In the expression: 0 : allZero s
      In an equation for `allZero': allZero (0 : s) = 0 : allZero s
```

and my code is:

```
allZero :: [Int] -> Bool
allZero (0:_) = True
allZero (0:s) = 0 : allZero s
allZero (_:s) = False;
allZero _ = False
```

I don't understand why im getting this error, in the line of `allZero (0:s) = 0 : allZero s` im giving it the correct parameter, a list 's'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain the error and the solution. The solution should be:

```
allZero :: [Int] -> Bool
allZero [] = True
allZero (x:xs) = (x == 0) && (allZero xs)
```

Think of the two patterns. First, if there is no elements, all are 0, that has sense, that is the first pattern `[]`.
 In the second pattern you ask if the first is `0` and you say that value `&&` all the rest of the elements must be `0` (using recursion)

In your example:

```
allZero :: [Int] -> Bool
allZero (0:_) = True --Wrong, here you are saying if it start with 0, True, no matter what is next, and that's not correct
allZero (0:s) = 0 : allZero s -- this could be right along side with other patterns
allZero (_:s) = False -- this is wrong by sure, you are saying if a list has at list one element, False
allZero _ = False -- And this one has no sense among the others
```

You have a lot of patterns, and incorrect. You can change my first answer as the equivalent:

```
allZero :: [Int] -> Bool
allZero []     = True
allZero (0:xs) = (allZero xs)
allZero _      = False
```

Comment: Though laziness only gets you so far: `&&` is strict in its first argument, but lazy in its second. `False && undefined` evaluates to `False`, but `undefined && False` raises an exception.

Answer (score 10):

The line:

```
allZero (0:s) = 0 : allZero s
```

does not make much sense, since `0 : allZero s` means you are constructing a list, a list of numbers. But you want to return a `Bool`.

Furthermore the line:

```
allZero (0:_) = True
```

Is incorrect as well, since that means that means that every list that starts with `0` satisfies the functions. But in a list `[0,1,4,2,5]`, not all numbers are `0`.

We can check this with:

```
allZero (Num a, Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allZero [] = True
allZero (0:s) = allZero s
allZero (_:_) = False
```

We can make use of [**`all :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) and write this as:

```
allZero :: (Num a, Eq a, Foldable f) => f a -> Bool
allZero = all (0 ==)
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, I have to learn how to highlight with html the answers like yours, pretty nice